# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I've been trying to view a table in a datagridview by using a the table name chosen in combobox but I still get the error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

I don't know what is wrong.

This is my code

```
Dim myconnection As New SqlConnection("data source=.\sqlexpress; initial catalog=itses;integrated security=true")
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim source1 As New BindingSource
        Dim table As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet

    myconnection.Open()

    Dim query As String
    query = "Select * from '" & ComboBox6.SelectedItem & "'"
    mycommand = New SqlCommand(query, myconnection)
    da.SelectCommand = mycommand
    da.Fill(table)
    source1.DataSource = table
    DataGridView2.DataSource = source1
    da.Update(table)
    myconnection.Close()
```

Comment: Could you please send us your call stack as well? It seems like you should also have an inner exception here. To me,  you don't need to add the quotes in your query string you are concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it's just the unneeded single quotes around the table name you're using - try this instead:

```
Dim query As String
query = "Select * from " & ComboBox6.SelectedItem
```

The query should be

```
Select * from TableName
```

(without any single quotes or anything else around the table name)

Comment: I guess the OP used single quotes for the possibility of spaces etc. in the table names, in which case square brackets would be needed instead.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding ToString() and removing `''` like so

```
 query = "Select * from "& ComboBox6.SelectedItem.ToString() &""
```

or just the `SelectedItem` should work

```
 query = "Select * from "& ComboBox6.SelectedItem &""
```